# Need some suggestion for libsrtp memory leak

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks

I am using libsrtp for my project. I am doing srtp_init() and internally it is calling below two function

```
crypto_kernel_init();
crypto_kernel_load_debug_module(&mod_srtp)
```

while destroying(srtp), I am calling

```
crypto_kernel_shutdown();
```

Now I am seeing below memory leak

```
==11435==   **25 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 19 of 42**
==11435==    at 0x4C2ABBD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==11435==    by 0x44F71D: crypto_alloc (alloc.c:97)
==11435==    by 0x44FDFE: null_cipher_alloc (null_cipher.c:64)
==11435==    by 0x44B12D: cipher_type_self_test (cipher.c:264)
==11435==    by 0x44EFD2: crypto_kernel_load_cipher_type (crypto_kernel.c:310)
==11435==    by 0x44F442: crypto_kernel_init (crypto_kernel.c:151)
==11435==    by 0x449C18: srtp_init (srtp.c:1082)

==11435== **232 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 34 of 42**
==11435==    at 0x4C2ABBD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==11435==    by 0x44F71D: crypto_alloc (alloc.c:97)
==11435==    by 0x451A39: aes_cbc_alloc (aes_cbc.c:71)
==11435==    by 0x44B12D: cipher_type_self_test (cipher.c:264)
==11435==    by 0x44EFD2: crypto_kernel_load_cipher_type (crypto_kernel.c:310)
==11435==    by 0x44F470: crypto_kernel_init (crypto_kernel.c:157)
==11435==    by 0x449C18: srtp_init (srtp.c:1082)
==11435== **256 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 35 of 42**
==11435==    at 0x4C2ABBD: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:296)
==11435==    by 0x44F71D: crypto_alloc (alloc.c:97)
==11435==    by 0x44C0BD: aes_icm_alloc_ismacryp (aes_icm.c:112)
==11435==    by 0x44C0BD: aes_icm_alloc (aes_icm.c:131)
==11435==    by 0x44B12D: cipher_type_self_test (cipher.c:264)
==11435==    by 0x44EFD2: crypto_kernel_load_cipher_type (crypto_kernel.c:310)
==11435==    by 0x44F459: crypto_kernel_init (crypto_kernel.c:154)
==11435==    by 0x449C18: srtp_init (srtp.c:1082)
```

Could you please guide to me what function needs to be called to resolve the memory leak issue?

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please guide to me what function needs to be called to resolve the memory leak issue?

No: A memory leak is either a bug in your way of using the library, or a bug in the library itself. So there's no "call this and be done" fix; you have to carefully read code and documentation to understand where you or your library allocate memory that you and your library don't release properly later on.

Don't be fooled by the results of your memory tracer, though: cryptological software often prefers to lose a few kB of memory that it doesn't give back to the operating system rather than letting cryptologically sensitive memory leak to other processes.

`srtp_init` probably has good documentation on what data structures you must de-initialize and how you can do it, if this is a relevant problem at all (which I don't really believe).

Comment: Could you please tell me which function need to execute to release the memory which is created at the time of srtp_init() function ?

Comment: Read the  first sentence of my answer.